# Unable to install ansible collections from a private git repository using Https and SSH link

Tags: git, github, collections, ansible

I am getting the below error it works with the tar file which i need to clone and install. As per ansible document we can install using the below methods.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository

why is it asking for tar file in my case?

[root@oc1546875**4 collections_repository1]# ansible-galaxy collection install git@github.i*m.com:samnanajeeb/test_collections.git
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Invalid collection name 'git@github.i*m.com', name must be in the format .. Please make sure namespace and collection name contains characters from [a-zA-Z0-9_] only.

[root@oc1546875**4 collections_repository2]# ansible-galaxy collection install https://github.i*m.com/Ansible-Self-Study/collections_repository1.git
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Collection artifact at '/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-7328qnvhfs/tmpOWt66o/collections_repository1SxEx78.git' is not a valid tar file.

Comment: The docs you linked to show that one must prefix `https:` with `git+https:` in order to advise ansible the URL does not just produce bytes but must be git installed. Knowing ansible coding practices, your first error is caused by them hard-coding github.com, so try `git+ssh://git@github.im.com/samn.../test_collections.git` to again advise it that the path needs to be git cloned

Comment: thank u i missed it. It worked

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository) specify that one must prefix `https:` with `git+https:` in order to advise ansible the URL does not just produce bytes but must be git installed. I would guess, based on my experiences with ansible coding practices, that your first error is caused by them hard-coding `github.com`, so try `git+ssh://git@github.im.com/samn.../test_collections.git` to (for the same reason) advise ansible that the path needs to be git cloned